# Достать номер телефона Авито

Tags: javascript, ajax, парсер, golang

Весь вопрос собственно в том, как получить номер телефона) я скачиваю html страничку и мне нужно как то сымитировать нажатие на кнопку "показать телефон". Как это сделать? Я в вебе новичок, но у меня есть примерное соображение: как я понимаю к этой кнопке привязан код на js и по нажатию уходит ajax запрос. После всего этого отображается номер.

Получается мне нужно 
1. Найти этот js ассоциированный с этой кнопкой
2. Выполнить этот скрипт
3. Получить json  ответ от сервера 
4. Найти информацию о телефоне в полученном json

А ещё смущает то, что на html страничке ни одного слова связанного с ajax не было найдено

Подскажите пожалуйста по тому ли пути я иду и если можно подкорректируйте его. Спасибо!

Comment: там номер приходит картинкой. И эту картинку можно получить в один аякс запрос

Comment: Аякс запрос в json же. Т.е. ответ формата json будет

Comment: да, правильно, в json картинка.

Comment: Я скопировал ссылку с которой связана кнопка Показать телефон и получил УРЛ по которому лежит это объявление и в конце #login))

Answer (score -1):

Если кто-то найдет это, то [вот решение](https://web.archive.org/web/20230329125537/https://fox-code.ru/a/kak-sparsit-nomer-telefona-s-avito/) по парсингу номера в Авито -

Вкратце, надо прикидываться мобильным устройством, и получать ответ через их мобильное api. Собственно по ссылке выше и указано как это сделать без бана.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]